# React-Hook-Form setValue for Material-UI Autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm building a form with React-Hook-Form and Material-UI. Each Material-UI form component is wrapped into a react-hook-form Controller component.

The user has the option to populate the form automatically with different sets of pre-defined values when clicks on a button. I'm trying to use `setValue()` to achieve that and it seems to work fine for text input and select. However, for autocomplete the new value is not rendered although when submitting the form it is correctly sent. Also, when a text area is rendered the content seems to be mixed with the label.

Here is a complete example:
[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-dew-sj9mv?file=/src/FormTextInput.tsx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cotroll the value of `AutoComplete` by passing value attribute to `AutoComplete` component, But since you are using string value you couldn't pass value to `AutoComplete` directly and you should to find the target `option` like this:

```
<Autocomplete
      ...
      value={typeof value === 'string' ? options.find(o => o.name === value) : (value || null)}
    />
```

Your textarea problem occurs because your value by default is `undefined` and material considers the textare as `uncotrolled` input, to solve it you can pass empty string when value is `undefined`, like this:

```
<TextField
        ...
        value={value || ''}
        ...
  />
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: It worked for me too.